# How can I give a svg a background image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a .jpg file and an .svg file and my goal is to make the .jpg file as background of the svg file but I did not find any way, is there such a possibility?

My goal I try to achieve is:

[image]

Comment: to me it does not even seem a task for a SVG but a simple image or background-image using `clip-path`

Answer (score 0):

**Context**

You can use an SVG just like any other image, using

- `background: url('my.svg')` or
- `<img src="my.svg" />`

To show one image over the other, you need two elements, each holding an image.

There are generally two ways to do this:

1. having two elements, each with a background, overlapping each other
2. one component with a background, that is displaying an image.

The parent will have to be `position: relative` and the children, absolute.

**Example 1**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.element1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/800/600');
  background-size: cover;
}

.element2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element1" />
  <div class="element2" />
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.element1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/800/600');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">
  <img alt="my text" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```